# Outlook Addin: Moving Appointment in Calendar does not reflect new date/time in AppointmentItem (catch Calendar.ItemChange)

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

i am trying to develop an Outlook Addin which updates a web services whenevery the ser moves an appointment (with drag and drop) in his calendar.
In my VSTO based Outlook Addin (in Outlook 2016) my Item_Change gets fired when the user moves the calendar item around. 
But when I inspect the AppointmentItem which I get as a parameter of the call to

```
public void Item_Change(Object item)
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem myAppointment = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
```

the myAppointment.StartUTC still shows the old value instead of the value (date/time) where the user has moved the item.

Does anyone know how to retrieve the new date/time of a moved AppointmentItem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please view the possible solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376400/vsto-outlook-plugin-cannot-get-appointmentitem-in-item-change-event-when-recurr/61184309#61184309

Answer (score 0):

Not using the Outlook Objector Model - it likes caching old stale values. All items are affected, but appointments are the worst - sometimes you would also need to change the current folder and come back. You would need to release the item in question, open another item, and only then open this item by its entry id. The problem you cannot do that from the event handler of the item that raises the event.

Your only other options are Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or Redemption.